# Graphics packages for publishing

Tags: software

What are the most popular packages used to create graphs for astronomy journal papers?
Looking at various journals, the styles of the graphs appear to be quite uniform but I can't identify the package(s) that create them.

Comment: is it [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) publishing tool you are after? This is great, but takes a little time to handle properly.

Comment: Yes, but i'm talking about the graphs that will be inserted into the LaTeX document. (Question clarified.)

Comment: Show us an example! Maybe you're looking for [GNUPLOT](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnuplot)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with astronomy

Comment: What tools are you using to generate data in the first place?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- I disagree slightly, in that it *is* a question about the *practice* of astronomy and the technical tools used. (Software is a tool in astronomy almost or just as much as telescopes are.)

Comment: @PeterErwin the technical tools used for scientific data analysis are almost 100% topic-agnostic.  Further,  it's possible to draw any style graph in any software package.  It's just a lot easier with the right package, e.g.,  R- ggplot.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- yes, but as a matter of scientific *culture* and *practice*, they're not "topic agnostic". SuperMongo, for instance, was created by astronomers and is used almost exclusively by astronomers. IDL originates from a context of atmospheric science, space physics, and astronomy, and has remained popular in those fields, but little used outside them, except perhaps for medical imaging.

Comment: @PeterErwin and perhaps one should ask: why is it that `R`  and `Python` have come to dominate and IDL is fading?  It's because you can do all that and more with these two top candidates.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- Agreed, plus the fact that both R and Python are open source, while SuperMongo is expensive and IDL is *very* expensive (certainly one of the motivations driving my shift from IDL to Python...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most commonly used packages for generating graphics in astronomy are probably

- [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_(programming_language)) -- this has long been the most popular, in part because there is a lot of astronomical data reduction and analysis code written in IDL.
- [SuperMongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM_(plotting))
- The Python package [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org)

The apparently uniform style you refer to is probably a historical combination of IDL and SuperMongo.

Matplotlib (and other Python packages that act as wrappers around it) is on a trajectory to displace the others; I strongly suspect it is already much more common than SuperMongo, and may be roughly as common as IDL by now.

You will sometimes see figures produced by the [PLplot library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLplot) as output from programs written
in Fortran, C/C++, etc. Plots produced using R are also starting to appear.